# Visual Studio 2012 with ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, visual-studio-2012

Anyone got ClearCase integration working inside Visual Studio 2012?
Removing ".NET Integration" from the IBM Installation Manager and then re-adding it did not make any difference.
Maybe manually registering the Add-In along with all the registry entries under VS 11.0 instead 10.0 will do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033485
Installing the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 integration with Rational ClearCase

Answer (score 2):

At the moment neither 712x or 800x support VS2012 integration, modify remove/add or reinstall wont do the trick right now.

To re-detect VS versions you can use IM to modify remove  the feature for VS integration, then use it again to add it back, no need to reinstall the whole thing.

Update:

Today this message came out:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21615206

You can follow the instructions at the referenced doc to get VS2012 integration!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327132,

> If you install a new version of Microsoft Visual Studio .NET after the installation of IBM Rational ClearCase or IBM Rational ClearQuest with Visual Studio .NET integration, you must reinstall the VisualStudio.NET integration feature.

So the installation order matters.

However, it depends on your ClearCase version:

The [Supported 3rd Party Integrations for ClearCase 7.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974#3rd) only mentions Visual Studio 2010 and below (no VS2012)

The "[System Requirements for Rational ClearCase 8.0.0.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27020796)" doesn't mention VS2012 at all.

So the integration support might not be there yet for VS2012.

Comment: @user895440 what I usually do is uninstall ClearCase itself, then re-install it (it detect the Visual Studio then). I assume you have at least CC7.1.x (full client)

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm not sure I want to try uninstalling the whole thing as I may not be able to set it back on properly...Btw, yes running 7.1.2.5

Comment: @user895440 I have done it on previous versions (of ClearCase and Visual Studio), but haven't tested it yet on Visual 2012.

Comment: @user895440 just edited the answer with more data: no official support for VS2012 for now.